# AS3: Nested functions + self reference VS constructor-level functions and variables

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, global-variables

I have two ways to structure my class, and I was wondering which way would be considered more correct.

Option #1 is to declare all my variables and functions inside the constructor to keep them local, but the problem is my nested functions think `this` means `[Object Global]` instead of `[Object MyObject]`. So in the constructor, I have to create a reference to the object `var thisObject:MyObject = this;` and use `thisObject` instead of `this` in my nested functions.

Options #2 is to declare all my variables and functions outside of and at the same level as the constructor. This means my variables are global to the class, and I was under the impression that you should try to keep your variables local whenever possible. Also, my constructor accepts parameters, so I would have to create a duplicate global version for each of them for my global functions to use.

Which way would be considered best practice?

Option #1

```
public class MyObject extends sprite {

    public function MyObject(myInt:int) {
        var thisObject:MyObject = this;
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nesetedCallbackFunction);
        function nestedCallbackFunction(evt:MouseEvent):void {
            trace(this); //[Object Global]
            trace(thisObject); //[Object MyObject]
            thisObject.x += myInt;
        }
    }
}
```

Option #2

```
public class MyObject extends sprite {

    var myIntProperty:int;

    public function MyObject(myInt:int) {
        myIntProperty = myInt;
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,globalCallbackFunction);
    }
    public function globalCallbackFunction(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        this.x += myIntProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Anonymous functions are bad form in AS3 and should not be used. What is the problem with keeping variables and functions private? that way only the object itself has access to these functions/variables. And Constructors (as well as functions) support optional parameters.

Comment: I think that the second one is better that the first.

Comment: The problem with the 2nd one is that if I have 10 parameters, then I need to make 10 duplicate variables for my functions outside the constructor to use.

Comment: First way is not good practice and is considered crappy code. Furthermore, if trying to find a job you show example one, there's no way anybody will hire you. Having 10 parameters is bad practice as well and should be kept for exceptional and justified needs. Only parameters that are directly needed for the constructor should be used then public member variables or getter/setter should be used for setting other variables.

Comment: exactly. Or use something like a Initializing Object with custom data, and only set the necessary variables as needed. Similiar to the way that greensock tweening engine defines what variables should actually get tweened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 is better, but read up on composition and encapsulation.

In option 2, you don't need to pass all properties of an object as parameters in the constructor. Just change your variables to be public:

```
public var myIntProperty:int;
```

Then when you create an object you can update it's properties when necessary:

```
var myObject:MyObject = new MyObject();
myObject.myIntProperty = 10;
```

A even better way would be to encapsulate the property so that you have more control over what it can be set to. For example, if you know you're int should only be in range 0-10, you could do this:

```
public class MyObject extends sprite {

    public function set myIntProperty(value:int):void {
        if(value >= 0 && value <= 10)
            _myIntProperty = value;
    }
    public function get myIntProperty():int {
        return _myIntProperty;
    }
    private var _myIntProperty:int;
}
```

You use this exactly the same way:

```
var myObject:MyObject = new MyObject();
myObject.myIntProperty = 10;
```

If you really have that many parameters that you need to send directly to the constructor, you're best bet is instead to simply pass a single Object with multiple properties. Then your constructor can read each of those properties and decide how to use them:

```
public class MyObject extends sprite {

    private var _myIntProperty:int;

    public function MyObject(params:Object)
    {
        if(params.intProperty >= 0 && params.intProperty <= 10)
            _myIntProperty = params.intProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add that in the range example that it would be good practice to throw an error if value is lower than 0 or greater than 10, so anyone that tries to set to myIntProperty to a value out of the range know they shouldn't. Otherwise they could introduce bugs and then spend a lot of time debugging.